# AVRDUDE does not write flash

Tags: avr, avrdude, winavr

I'm having a problem with [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/). It does not even attempt to write the hex file to the AVR. In [WinAVR](http://winavr.sourceforge.net/) there is no problem. (I can't use WinAVR, because I've got only the hex file.)

```
L:\>avrdude -c SAJAT -p t2313 -P COM1 -U flash:w:main.hex

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e910a

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:DF, L:E0)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

avrdude.exe, avrdude.conf and the main.hex files are located in the same folder.

SAJAT is my version of the DASA programmer (different pin assignment), and this works fine. The target is [ATtiny2313](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY2313.aspx) with an external 12 MHz clock. I am using AVRDUDE 6.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Writing fuse bits works.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I've only uploaded a hex file, but I don't know if this will work with EEPROM files as well or not.

- Step 1:
  Create a simple program in WinAVR, like an LED toggle.
  Name it as you like. I named it 2313.c
- Step 2:
  Compile it in WinAVR.
  Now you have not only the 2313.c file, also the 2313.hex and other files as well.
- Step 3:
  Burn this into the target device with WinAVR. This is important for future steps. Don't close the program after burning is completed.
- Step 4:
  Rename the hex file you want to burn to your AVR to 2313.hex (myhex_to_burn.hex -> 2313.hex). Copy the renamed hex and overwrite the complied one with it. Now copy all these files (makefile, .hex, .c, ... etc.) where your AVRDUDE is located.
- Step 5:
  Open AVRDUDE. (Start -> cmd - > go to AVRDUDE location.)
  Open WinAVR and select the first line at its Output window. You should find something like this:

  ```
  avrdude -p attiny2313 -P com1     -c sajat    –U flash:w:2313.hex
  ```

  Copy it and paste it into AVRDUDE with right click and insert.
- Step 6:
  Prepare your target AVR for programing (connect it to the ISP programmer, power, etc.)
  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.